# Link to ICQ account

Tags: icq

I have same HyperLink :

```
HyperLink skype = new HyperLink(); skype.NavigateUrl = "skype:username?call";
```

When user press it he redirects to skype window to user account, which entered in NavigateUrl.
I try to find something for ICQ in google, but fail.
Does anybody know how to link to ICQ account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this URL:

http://www.icq.com/whitepages/cmd.php?uin=4655465&action=message

Replacing the UIN with the one you want, and the message with the one you want.

Obviously it only works if they have ICQ installed.

[From this web post.](http://www.bigblueball.com/forums/other-instant-messengers/31039-url-launch-icq-client.html)

Comment: After press this (http://www.icq.com/whitepages/cmd.php?uin=4655465&action=message) link download window apears for cmd.php file. So I don't undestande what you mean. May be it doesn't work because I use ICQ Infium.
Also I find url to user account on isq.com : http://www.icq.com/people/about_me.php?uin=123456, but it isn't I want.

Comment: It tries to download file with mime type application/x-icq, which is registered to icq and initiates chat with the contact in question.

Comment: and yes, it is very likely, that other ICQ clients do not handle it.

Comment: Thank you, I get it. But If I use multiprotocol client (QIP Infium) it doesn't work.
Also I'm  ineresting in what about Jabber? Are there any way to make jabber button?

Comment: This website responds with HTTP 404.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is:

`https://icq.im/<ICQ UIN>`

For example:

`https://icq.im/123456789`

where you substitute your UIN ICQ number for `123456789`.